# use of static keyword in Mapper class in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am new to MapReduce. I have seen many codes written in MapReduce and declaring static variables.

**Example:**

```java
public class Map extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
   private static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private Text word = new Text();

   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context){
        //Mapper code
     }
   }
 }
```

But have a doubt, I know for every Map task is instantiated in separate JVM. So how do the Mapper instances share the static variable(s)? If they cannot share, what is the use of static variable(s)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280415/hadoop-map-reduce-task-and-static-variable).

Answer (score 2):

In short, **they don't**.

Your java compiled class will be distribucted, e.g. sent to each node that will run the code. This way each node has **a copy** of your bytecode, being executed in its own JVM.

So, this technique of declaring fields that don't change theirs values between diferent map() method calls (done by the framework), is done to avoid unnecessary instances of the same object in the same JVM, throughout multiple executions.

[]s!