# Static method updating a static value (Hadoop MapReduce)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following Hadoop mapper class:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<NullWritable, RepublicRecord, NullWritable, Text> {

    private Text output = new Text();
    private NullWritable nothing = NullWritable.get();

    private static String[] outputFields = new String[0];

    public void map(NullWritable key, RepublicRecord value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = StringUtils.join(value.GetData(outputFields), ",");
        output.set(line);
        context.write(nothing, output);
    }

    public static void SetOutputFields(String fieldString) {
        outputFields = fieldString.split(",");
    }
}
```

I call `Map.SetOutputFields("one,two")`, then I call `map(key, value, context)`. When I do, a 0-length string array gets passed to `value`'s `GetData()` method.

I would expect that a string array containing "one" and "two" would get passed to `GetData()` instead...

What's going on here? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Where do you call `SetOutputFields`? (Unrelated, but the naming goes against canonical Java naming conventions.)

Comment: multithreading maybe?

Comment: It's hadoop, so multithreading is definitely a possible explanation here.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Something else seems to be wrong. I would use a Debugger to single step through the code and check the variable values.

Comment: Also... on the naming convention... My understanding is that private methods usually start with a lowercase letter, public with uppercase. Is that not the case?

Comment: Methods usually start with a lowercase regardless of visibility

Comment: That is not the case. I missed that this was Hadoop; it's worth mentioning stuff like that in the question and/or tags because I glossed over the method signature.

Comment: Good call. I had initially left off the reference to Hadoop because I assumed I was making a very generic Java error (I'm new to the language).

Comment: This appears to be my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280415/hadoop-map-reduce-task-and-static-variable Separate JVMs...

Comment: Sure, running programs on completely separate machines would tend to do that :/